# TimescaleDB - how get timestamp differences between rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

Say you need to know how long something was 'active' in a time range - (with timestamp in minutes, as an example) -

```
timestamp, state
2.1, unavailable
3.5, active
6.8, wait
7.3, unavailable
9.3, active
```

For a 0-15min bucket, the answer would be 6.8-3.5 + 15-9.3 = 9.0mins. (ie the first active state lasts 6.8-3.5mins, the next one goes from 9.3mins to the 15min barrier).

How would you do something like this in TimescaleDB?

Comment: Huh? This makes no sense. How was this; `6.8-3.5 + 15-9.3` determined? I see no pattern to the equation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver edited for more clarity

Comment: Extended this question here - need to be able to group results into bins also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246220/timescaledb-how-get-timestamp-differences-between-rows-and-group-results-into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data does not correspond to the implied data type (3.5 is not a timestamp). However, it appears you are trying to get the sum of the difference between consecutive entries. If so use the lead function to get the next value (coalesce with 15 for the last entry) then sum the difference for active state. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=daee1be7d470b772d6679815a40733ad))

```
select sum(nts-ts) 
  from ( select ts ,coalesce(lead(ts) over( order by ts),15) nts, state from t) s
 where state = 'active'
```

Comment: Thank you, @Belayer - that works - I didn't know about coalesce.